# How to set the default python path for anaconda on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I have installed anaconda on a Linux machine. I noticed that after deactivating the anaconda environment with:

```
source deactivate
```

When running:

```
which python
```

I get:

```
/home/user/anaconda/bin/python
```

Instead of

```
/usr/bin/python
```

How can I restore this setting?

Comment: I'm quite confused about what you want to do here. Your question title suggests you want to use the system Python with packages installed in an Anaconda environment. If this is your question, I would not recommend proceeding that way, as I think it will not work well. If, on the other hand, you would like to just use the system Python with its own packages, the answer is that you have to manually rewrite your `PATH` variable, you cannot deactivate the root Anaconda environment. Please clarify, and I think I can answer :-)

Comment: Hi, Anaconda is a virtualenv, so if i 'source deactivate' it, shouldn't it be deactivated? What is a root Anaconda environment? I want the default python to be root Anaconda environment instead of  /home/user/anaconda/bin/python. Should i determine the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Hi! Anaconda is *not* a virtualenv, it is a separate distribution of Python that you install on your computer. Within the Anaconda distribution, you can `activate` and `deactivate` environments that *act* like virtualenvs. However, the root environment is installed when you install Anaconda, and cannot be deactivated, except by not using Anaconda. Why do you want to use the system default Python with Anaconda? Why not use the version of Python that Anaconda installed?

Comment: Hi, i had a confusion and i thought that anaconda is the a venv. What is the difference between PTYHON_PATH and PATH  envs?

Comment: That's really a separate question, so if this doesn't make sense, I'd recommend doing some more research and possibly asking another question. Basically, `PYTHONPATH` is where Python looks to import packages, whereas `PATH` is where the system (e.g. Ubuntu) looks to run executables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments somewhat cover the answer to the question, but to clarify:

When you installed Anaconda you must have agreed to have it added to your PATH.  You'll want to check in your `~/.bash*` files and look for any `export PATH=` lines to check this.  So Anaconda is **always** on your path.  The `source deactivate` command will only deactivate "sub" Conda environments.  It will never remove what is called the "root" Conda environment (the one you originally installed).  If you don't want Anaconda on your `PATH` by default then remove it from your `~/.bash*` startup files.  Then when you want to use Anaconda you'll need to add it to your `PATH`.  Or just add the specific Conda environment you are interested in to your `PATH` directly, and don't worry about the `activate` and `deactivate` scripts.  At their core all they do is modify `PATH`.

I hope that helps clarify things.

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda comes with its own everything, and they ask if you wish to use their software as a default when you install it by adding their bin first to your PATH variable. If you do that, you can only manually remove it later from .bashrc to undo this action.

I chose not to do it, but i made a shell script to start spyder and use the anaconda distribution when i wish to, without altering my PATH by calling spyder like this from the shell script:

```
PATH=/home/<... path to where i installed anaconda>/bin:$PATH spyder &
```

This means that i am adding their distribution's bin to the path only for the extent of running that command (spyder), otherwise my environment is unaffected by anaconda.

If i wish to add things to it, i pass an option to the shell when i source it and that triggers these actions:

```
PATH=/home/<... path to where i installed anaconda>/bin:$PATH
PS1='\[\033[1;34m\](A)\w:\[\033[0m\] '
```

so that i see (with colors!) that in this terminal i am using an altered PATH, the one with python3 and such from anaconda, etc... When done, i kill the terminal! :)

Answer (score 1):

To get back to the former default, I comment out the entry setting the pathbin the `.bashrc` file and get these results:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python -v
python 2.7.*
```

Comment: **quick fix** Just run this command then use python

`export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH`

Comment: **proper fix** look into the `.bashrc` file in your home directory for similar line which adds the anaconda path to `PATH` variable and remove it (or comment it out).

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed something, you want to use it before older installs, in general.

Your path is well set: your install is searched before system install.

If you want to use system python, run `% /usr/bin/python`.

If you don't want anaconda, just trash it (or move it somewhere ouside of path).

This may help:
`% which -a python`.